# Add Performance Counter Category Hangs Computers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows, c#-4.0, performancecounter

I am trying from a ASP.NET MVC Application (with VS 2012 on Windows 8 x64 PC) to add a Perfomance Counter but I have the problem that if I check the category exists or add a new Performance Counter Category the computer hangs

My code is:

```
namespace TestMvcCounter
{
  public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
  {
      protected void Application_Start()
      {
          AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

          WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
          FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
          RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
          BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

          if (!PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists("MY_TEST"))
          {
              CounterCreationDataCollection ccdc = new CounterCreationDataCollection();
              ccdc.Add(new CounterCreationData() { CounterName = "# loops", CounterType = PerformanceCounterType.RateOfCountsPerSecond32 });

              PerformanceCounterCategory.Create("MY_TEST", "Test performance counter", PerformanceCounterCategoryType.MultiInstance, ccdc);
          }

      }
   }
}
```

and when the code reach this line

```
!PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists("MY_TEST")
```

the system hangs without any exception or timeout

Do you know what could be that cause the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a deep search I figured out the problem was IIS Express 8.

I tried to unistall it and re-install but didn't work, then I tried to unistall again and install the IIS Express 7.5 and it works

Comment: Can you provide more details? I might have the same issue, but with VisualStudio 2015 and IISExpress 10.

Comment: We are facing exactly the same issue on VS 2019. I've tried to uninstall and install different versions of IIS Express unsuccessfully.