# Performance Counter hangs, when accessed by a web application

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, iis-express, performancecounter

I am working on a diagnosis `IHttpHandler` handler, that should list critical indicators from a WCF service, such as "Calls Per Second", "Calls", "Calls Failed", "Calls Duration" etc.

First of all, I did a lot of googeling, because there a several reported cases of a hanging Performance Counters. I have the same problem as described here:
[Add Performance Counter Category Hangs Computers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194163/add-performance-counter-category-hangs-computers)
This problem still occours on IISExpress 10 and Visual Studio 2015. There is no problem, when hosted in IIS.

The following source codes work in a WinForms application, `IHttpModule` hosted in IIS, but the `IHttpModule` hangs, when hosted in IISExpress

```
PerformanceCounter PC = new PerformanceCounter();
PC.CategoryName = "ServiceModelEndpoint 4.0.0.0";
PC.CounterName = "Calls Per Second";
PC.InstanceName = "WkisCoreService.IWkisCoreService@33Service.svc|WS2007HTTPBINDING";
float value = PC.NextValue(); // Hanging here
```

Or

`PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories();`

Or

```
PerformanceCounterCategory category = 
            new PerformanceCounterCategory("ServiceModelEndpoint 4.0.0.0");
string[] instances = category.GetInstanceNames(); // Hanging here
```

The is no timeout or exception. It seems to hang endlessly, when called from the `IHttpModule`.

Any ideas solving this problem in order to be able to develop/debug in IISExpress?

Comment: Does it hang always or just sometimes?

Comment: It's hanging always. On Monday I am going to try to host the service in a regular IIS, in order to find out, if IISExpress is causing the problem.

Comment: I can confirm, that this still seems to be an IISExpress problem. I updated my post

Comment: Hi Dominik, could you be able to solve this issue?
I'm facing this problem when activating 64bit for web projects on Visual Studio settings.
No lucky to address the issue even updating IIS Express version.  Currently using version 10.0.19401.1 of IIS Express.

Comment: Still facing this issue here.
Any news about it, could someone address this issue somehow?

Comment: @FernandoJaconete After nearly exactly four years I can't remember for sure what the solution was (we are now using .NET Core) but I think the issue was a permission issue. 

The AppPool needs permission in "Performance Monitor Users" (how to set AppPool User: https://serverfault.com/questions/81165/how-to-assign-permissions-to-applicationpoolidentity-account/81246#81246 ). Afterwards the IIS needs to be restarted.

Comment: @DominikAmon, thanks a lot for your return, however, this is related to IIS Express, everything runs fine hosted on IIS. Unfortunately, I could'nt get rid of this issue. Got some temporary workaround by changing registry keys for Performance entries, but it got to work once or twice at most, then issue comes back. The definitive solution was to place some compile directives in order to not call performance counter code when debugging. That worked for us considering the issue is related to IIS Express, but not it's still not a good solution.